# How to programmatically resume an Activity from a notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-notifications

I've been reading a lot of answers on the topic but none of them resolve this issue.

The app is running a "foreground service" so a notification is required.

This is how the `Intent` is created.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, notificationClass);
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Note that the `Activity` class to launch from the notification is known at runtime (`notificationClass`). For extra context, there's a library that exposes a `View` which when inflated creates the `Service` which creates the `Notification` and because any `Activity` could include the `View`, the `Class` is requested so that when the user clicks the notification resumes the correct `Activity`.

Then, the `intent` is added to the `notificationBuilder` (`NotificationCompat.Builder`).

```
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
```

Implementing this when the app goes to the background and then the notification is clicked, it creates a fresh copy of the `Activity` instead of resuming it.

For testing purposes, I got the expected behavior (the `Activity` is resumed after clicking the notification) by adding the `launchMode` of the `Activity` (know beforehand) to `singleTop` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. But I wasn't able to get it working in any other way.

With these constraints I'm wondering if it's possible to get the same behavior programmatically when the `Notification` is created. I've tried a bunch of `Intent` flags combinations (also `addFlags` vs `setFlags`) without luck.

Is there any possibility of creating an `Intent` to behave as explained?

Thanks a lot!

cc'ing https://stackoverflow.com/users/769265/david-wasser that has answered a lot of similar `Intent`-related questions

Comment: When the user clicks on the notification, do you just want to bring the existing task to the foreground (in whatever state it was in)? Or do you explicitly want to start a specific `Activity`?

Comment: @DavidWasser what I want is to resume the `Activity` from the notification i.e. same scenario as if you would open the recent task list and select an `Activity` to resume. Does that make sense? I guess is a mix, so bringing the existing task to the foreground but for a specific `Activity`. Let me know if you need further clarification. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error testing, I got it working using the following combination of methods

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
intent.setPackage(null);
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);enter code here
```

The key part here was `intent.setPackage(null);`

```
/**
 * (Usually optional) Set an explicit application package name that limits
 * the components this Intent will resolve to.  If left to the default
 * value of null, all components in all applications will considered.
 * If non-null, the Intent can only match the components in the given
 * application package.
 *
 * @param packageName The name of the application package to handle the
 * intent, or null to allow any application package.
 *
 * @return Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls
 * into a single statement.
 *
 * @see #getPackage
 * @see #resolveActivity
 */
```

So apparently, `pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());` returns an `Intent` limited to the components in `context.getPackageName()` and setting the package explicitly to `null` is needed afterwards so that all components are considered.

I'm not completely sure about ^ though. FWIW adding it, solved the issue ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It worked, but not possible pass some flag from notification to activity. Need to know resumed from notification or from recent list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand, but if you just want to bring the existing task to the foreground (which is the same as selecting a task from the list of recent tasks), then try this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

the `packageName` is the name of the package in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This "launches" the root `Activity` for the task, which will not actually launch anything but just brings the existing task to the foreground.

Comment: I've tested that and it's not working as you explained. It's creating a new copy of the "main activity" (i.e. the one that has `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` as action and category) and adding it to the top of the backstack. That is to say, when creating A > B > C activities what I want is to go back to C (preserving the backstack) when clicking to the notification and now what I'm getting is A > B > C > A
Does that make sense now? Thanks again!

Comment: When I say now I mean with the snippet you shared above. If it's clearer now, do you know how to get C back after clicking the notification programmatically? Like if you select an `Activity` to resume from the Recents screen. Let me know also if you think is not possible or if you have a workaround to do the same. I thought that this was a common use case but it doesn't seem so :( Thank you!

Comment: You may be seeing a nasty Android bug. This causes the root `Activity` to be restarted in certain cases. To check, please "force close" your app and then open it again by clicking on the icon on the HOME screen. Do not open the app directly from the installer or from AndroidStudio. See if the problem goes away. If not, please post your manifest. The behaviour you describe makes no sense.

Comment: I've just tested what you suggested and it's not working as you mentioned. It's creating a new root `Activity` and placing it at the top. Here you can find the manifest https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
I also created a branch with your suggested changes so you can test it yourself https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/tree/pg-resume-activity-from-notification

Comment: So for example if you open the app and navigate to the `WaypointNavigationActivity` and then press the home button and then click on the notification, `MainActivity` is created and placed on top when what I want is to resume `WaypointNavigationActivity`. Please, let me know if that makes sense and if it's possible to achieve. Thanks again @DavidWasser

Comment: Please do the following: run your app and do whatever you do to put the app in the background and cerate the notification. Before clicking on the notification do `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and save this data. Then click on the notification and execute the `adb` command again. Copy both outputs to a file somewhere and put a link here.

Comment: There you go https://gist.github.com/Guardiola31337/1cccb17fef92888c180de97325207388 This is `MainActivity` > `WaypointNavigationActivity` > Put the app in the background (clicking on the home button) > `adb` command > data before clicking on the notification > click on the notification > `adb` command > data after clicking on the notification - creating the `Intent`/`PendingIntent` as you suggested.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. The behaviour you are seeing is not correct. Android should bring the existing task forward and not create a new instance of the `Activity`. At this point I would suggest you try creating a simple app that addresses only this problem. Your app is quite complicated to sort through to figure out what is going on.

Comment: What device are you testing on? What version of Android is running on that device? Have you tested on multiple devices?

Comment: I've tested it in a couple of devices - Moto X (2nd gen) running Android 5.0 and Nexus 5 running Android 6.0 - and in both I'm seeing the same weird behavior :(
I've created a simple app that reproduces the commented behavior https://github.com/Guardiola31337/notification so you can test it out yourself.
I'm running out of ideas to get it working... Could you please take a look at it and let me know what else I can try? Thanks for all your help @DavidWasser